# Evidence for floats beyond -1/+1 for wav

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, wav

The description of https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.write.html suggests that floats are only between -1 and +1, but I would like to save regular floats that can be larger/smaller. I tried it out with my data that is float64 in type and it seemed to worked (I read it back with `scipy.io.wavfile.read`), so I am inclined to believe this is possible. Is there a reference that supports this? I could find any in the web.

Comment: Your best reference is probably the code itself: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/io/wavfile.py. Notice the actual data writing happens at the bottom of that file: it just writes a bytes view to disk. Hence, your floating point number are interpreted as bytes and written as such. Reading will do the reverse, so that'll indeed work fine. Of course, that doesn't mean any other application will be able to interpret your files correctly.

Comment: @Evert: So why does the documentation says what it does? Does this mean that having numbers beyond -1/+1 for float32 will also work?

Comment: The documentation states what the WAV format prescribes. It doesn't say that scipy doesn't let you save values outside that range. Think of it as a speed limit: your car (manufacturer) allows you to go over it, but the law prescribes that that is the limit. Up to you if you pass the limit: consequences are on you.

Comment: @Evert: Okay... but what are the consequences in this case if I go beyond? Or is this simply a rule for audio files?